# UIButton: manually calling touchesBegan does not set isHighlighted

Tags: ios, uibutton, uicontrolstate

The `isHighlighted` property on `UIButton`is mostly analogous to whether the button is pressed or not.

The Apple docs are vague about it:

> Controls automatically set and clear this state in response to
>   appropriate touch events.
>   https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/1618231-ishighlighted

Which method is the system calling to set this?

It appears to be `touchesBegan`, because you can override this method to prevent it.

But, surprisingly, if you **manually** call `touchesBegan` it doesn't get set (for example, from a superview-- see code below).

So it seems it's not simple as `touchesBegan`. I've tried overriding every method I could...`pressesBegan`, `pressesChanged`, `pressesCancelled`, `pressesEnded`, `touchesCancelled`, `beginTracking`, `continueTracking`, `hitTest`, etc.

Only `touchesBegan` had any effect.

Here's how I tried calling touchesBegan from a superview:

```
class MyView: UIView {

    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        return self
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let point = touches.first?.location(in: self) else { return }
        for view in self.subviews {
            if let button = view as? UIButton {
                if button.frame.contains(point) {
                    button.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
                    print("\(button.isHighlighted)") //prints false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```